# Using Floating button directly without declaring it as a variable

Tags: android-studio, button, layout, onclicklistener

I'm learning app development in Android Studio using Kotlin following a course and I'm getting confused. In the video, an `OnClickListener` is assigned to a button directly without declaring this button as a variable.

His code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fabAddHappyPlace.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, AddHappyPlaceActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }}
```

The `fabAddHappyPlace` is a floating button used in the `activity_main.xml`. There is an import at the top of the file:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Is this a way to not having to declare a variable for a View everytime? I tried it myself, using this piece of code as an import at the top of the file:

```
import com.example.happyplaces.R.layout.activity_main
```

If I want to add the `*` at the end, the compiler tells me there is no such file as `activity_main.xml`, but there is! Why doesn't this work for me and is this the normal way of working?

I can fix my problem by just declaring a variable and setting an `OnClickListener` on the button and it works fine, but I was just curious why I can't do it this way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's called Kotlin Synthetics. It was deprecated and removed from project templates quite a while ago, but there are still a bunch of tutorials that show it 'cause they never went back to update them. You can certainly declare and assign that yourself, if you'd like, or you could use View binding, which was kind of the replacement for Synthetics: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding.

Comment: No problem. For completeness' sake, I should also mention [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding), which is basically View binding that allows you to put some UI logic in the layout XML. Lastly, there's [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), which is a completely different paradigm than the `View` framework, but which seems to be where we're all headed eventually. There is no layout XML in Compose, so issues like this wouldn't even come up, and there'd be no need for data binding 'cause everything's in code already. Just FYI. Cheers!